# Problem with install seaborn module in Pycharm Application

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, seaborn, python-import

I am trying the import the seaborn module (using Python 3.7) into my project (I'm using the Pycharm application). Here's my code:

```
import os
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
import googleapiclient.discovery
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
```

Here's the error message that I got executing the above code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/test/main.py", line 6, in <module>
    import seaborn
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\seaborn\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .rcmod import *
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\seaborn\rcmod.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import palettes, _orig_rc_params
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\seaborn\palettes.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .utils import desaturate, set_hls_values, get_color_cycle
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\seaborn\utils.py", line 6, in <module>
    from scipy import stats
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py", line 136, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\_distributor_init.py", line 61, in <module>
    WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

Does anyone know why the seaborn module could not be found? I added the seaborn package already using the python interpreter.

Comment: Did you look at the `pip freeze` output? Did you see the `seaborn` package in the output?

Comment: Yeah, just looked at the installed modules with the `pip freeze` command, the seaborn module is there. @Ahmet